# Descargar imagenes en un zip

Tags: php, zip

Tengo este pedazo de codigo php, quiero descargar unas imagenes en un zip, pero las imagenes son de otro dominio pero está en el mismo servidor donde estoy trabajando

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
// Creamos y abrimos un archivo zip temporal
$zip->open("miarchivo.zip",ZipArchive::CREATE);
// Añadimos un directorio

// Añadimos un archivo en la raid del zip.
//comentados
$zip->addFile("inef/images/'".$si1."'","inefrontal.jpg");
//esta es la dirección del dominio
$zip->addFile("http://app.itink.info/victor/checkapp/pages/examples/si1/images/'".$si1."'","ineinversa.jpg");
```

Comment: debes pasarle la ruta absoluta no la url.

Comment: como la ruta absoluta, Bryro?

Comment: El /var/www/otro_proyecto/public/imagenes/file.jpg or por url seria asi.  $file =file_put_contents("temp.jpg", fopen($url, 'r')); y luego lo pasas a addFile